# Getting a cannot read property map of undefined, although the items state is set with data

Tags: reactjs

So I am trying to build a cart using react and express. The backend is working fine. I am using postman to test my endpoint and it is giving me the correct response. However, it is the react frontend that is causing problems.
I am trying to use `map` function on the `items` array which has been set to the response from the server, but it gives me an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Here is my code:

**Cart.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import CartItem from "./cart1-item.component.js";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { throws } from "assert";

export default class Cart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000/cart/")
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ items: response.data });
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  checkItems() {
    return this.state.items.items.map((currItem, i) => {
      return <CartItem book={currItem} key={i}></CartItem>;
    });
  }

  Calculate = item => {
    return item.qty * item.price;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">{this.checkItems()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**CartItem.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const CartItem = props =>
  props.items.map(item => {
    return <div>{item.title}</div>;
  });

export default CartItem;
```

And the postman response for '/cart'

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "item": "5dd7668f33c21d811b74f403",
            "title": "Modern PHP",
            "price": 25.65,
            "qty": 1
        }
    ],
    "total": 25.65
}
```

here is also the server.js code I dont understand why my array is empty when the postman is giving me a response, that indicates my endpoints work correctly.

```
cartRoutes.route("/").get(function(req, res) {
  var cart = req.session.cart;
  var displayCart = { items: [], total: 0 };
  var total = 0;

  for (var item in cart) {
    displayCart.items.push(cart[item]);
    total += cart[item].qty * cart[item].price;
  }
  displayCart.total = total;

  return res.json(displayCart);
});

cartRoutes.route("/:id").post(function(req, res) {
  req.session.cart = req.session.cart || {};
  var cart = req.session.cart;
  let id = req.params.id;
  Book.findById(id, function(err, book) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    if (cart[id]) {
      cart[id].qty++;
    } else {
      cart[id] = {
        item: book._id,
        title: book.title,
        price: book.price,
        qty: 1
      };
    }
    res.redirect("/cart");
  });
});
```

I have already spent a day and a half trying to resolve this on my own. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it is `this.state.items.items` ?

Comment: yeah i guess depending on the response from the server. I have posted the json also

Comment: how does `response.data` look like?

Comment: it is the json I have posted {
    "items": [
        {
            "item": "5dd7668f33c21d811b74f403",
            "title": "Modern PHP",
            "price": 25.65,
            "qty": 1
        }
    ],
    "total": 25.65
}

Comment: I think the problem here is, that while the component did mount the async request runs a bit further so at the point of render, you may not have the items in the state like you would expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another answer is pointing your `initialState` is incorrect as you are accessing in the `checkItems` method, you have to preserve the structure.

I could suggest to mantain certain stucture, in your case looks like this is your `initialState` :

```
this.state = {
      items: []
    };
```

So when you are calling you method `checkItems` you are accessing it the wrong way:

```
 checkItems() {
    return this.state.items.items.map((currItem, i) => {
      return <CartItem book={currItem} key={i}></CartItem>;
    });
  }
```

So as far as i can see when you receive your response you are modifying your `initialState` structure.

To fix this i suggest you this minor change (just change the `response.data` to `response.data.items`):

```
 componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000/cart/")
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ items: response.data.items });
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

And the method `checkItems` as well:

```
checkItems() {
    return this.state.items.map((currItem, i) => {
      return <CartItem book={currItem} key={i}></CartItem>;
    });
  }
```

Comment: @Bisma Look at this [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-star-t57m5), it solves several issues you where running

Comment: the page is blank and not showing the title as it is supposed to and when I inspect the page using developer tools, the items array is empty when I have set it to response.data.items

Comment: 404
We could not find the page you're looking for. for the sandbox

Comment: I have also added the backend code, please check why my array is empty still.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when you are loading the app, your initial state is wrong. `this.state.items` is an array, but `this.state.items.items` is `undefined`, and for the `.map()` function to work you need an array.
So your initial state should look something like this:

```
this.state = {
  items: {
    items: []
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the structures of your initial data and data from the api do not match. You need to change the `checkItems` method and also set the nested `items` to the state:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000/cart/")
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ items: response.data.items });  // set items to the state
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  checkItems() {
    return this.state.items.map((currItem, i) => { // items is one level deep now
      return <CartItem book={currItem} key={i}></CartItem>;
    });
  }
```

The reason for the error is that your initial state is `items: []`, which is what being used for the first render. So basically in `checkItems` you're trying to access `items` property of an empty array.

Edit: You're also accessing incorrect props in the child component, it'd be `book`, not `items`, since it's what you're passing:

```
const CartItem = ({book}) => {
  return <div>{book.title}</div> 
}
```

Comment: ok so I did this this.state = {
      items: {
        items: []
      } but how will I set the state using response.data.items

Comment: It's in the answer: `this.setState({ items: response.data.items });` Check the comments in the code.

Comment: yeah did that but still not displaying the result that is the title

Comment: I have also added the backend code to my question, please check why my array is empty still.

Comment: That probably should be asked in a separate question.